# when the LazyRow inside a ViewPager is scrolled to its end, it scrolls the ViewPager to the next page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have a ViewPager that contains two pages and inside each page there is a LazyColumn that shows a list of tasks. And inside that LazyColumn above those tasks I have a LazyRow item that shows the sorting options of the tasks. When the LazyRow scrolls to its end, the ViewPager also scrolls with it to the next page, but I don't want the LazyRow's scrolling to affect the ViewPager's scrolling.

[image: screenshot]

This was my attempt at solving the problem, it stopped the scrolling most of the time, but it still scrolled a little bit sometimes:

1 - i defined a top level mutable state variable called "viewPagerShouldScroll".

2 - inside that **LazyRow** :

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = lazyRowState.interactionSource){
            lazyRowState.interactionSource.interactions.collect{
                viewPagerShouldScroll = it !is DragInteraction.Start
            }
        }
```

also this , but when LazyRow reaches to the last visible items , it doesn't work:

`viewPagerShouldScroll = lazyListState.!isScrollInProgress`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that prevents to affect the ViewPager's scrolling. You can wrap LazyColumn into a traditional custom view that intercepts touch events. the traditional solution is [NestedScrollableHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587618/viewpager2-with-horizontal-scrollview-inside).
For instance:

```html
<cn.adp.appmarket.widget.NestedScrollableHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <cn.adp.appmarket.widget.SpecialComposeView
        android:id="@+id/mComposer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</cn.adp.appmarket.widget.NestedScrollableHost>
```

And here is a optimized method which work correctly in my case.

```
fun Modifier.compatibleWithViewPage(state: LazyListState) = composed {
val view = LocalView.current
val touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(view.context).scaledTouchSlop

val TOUCH_SLOP = 1f

val TOUCH_SLOP_HALF = .5f

var initialX = 0f
var initialY = 0f

then(Modifier.pointerInput(true) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        while (true) {
            val event = awaitPointerEvent(PointerEventPass.Initial)
            when (event.type) {
                PointerEventType.Press -> {
                    view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                    event.changes.firstOrNull()?.let {
                        initialX = it.position.x
                        initialY = it.position.y
                    }
                }

                PointerEventType.Move -> {
                    event.changes.firstOrNull()?.let {
                        val dx = it.previousPosition.x - initialX
                        val dy = it.previousPosition.y - initialY


                        val scaledDx = dx.absoluteValue * TOUCH_SLOP_HALF

                        val scaledDy = dy.absoluteValue * TOUCH_SLOP

                        if (scaledDx > touchSlop || scaledDy > touchSlop) {
                            if ((scaledDy > scaledDx)) {
                                view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                            } else {
                                if (state.canScrollBackward || state.canScrollForward) {
                                    view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

}

```
                val state = rememberLazyListState()
            LazyRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .compatibleWithViewPage(state)
            ) {
                items(recommendAreaUiState.apps, key = { it.bundleId }) {
                    RecommendItem(uiState = it) {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is my screen
[image]